# Postgres SELECT * FROM Table where array has element

Tags: sql, arrays, json, psql

I am using `Postgres 9.3.2` to make a database of **contacts**.

**Example:** If i have a row in my table that looks something like this.

```
{
    firstName : "First name"
    lastName : "Last name"
    emails : ["email@one.com", "email@two.com", "email@three.com]
}
```

PS: firstName, lastName and emails are columns in my db and the value associated is the value for that column for that specific row.

I want to be able to query the db so that if i query for the email "email@four.com" the result is nothing but if i query for "email@two.com" the result will be the above row entry.

I dont think the query

`"Select * from contactTable where emails="email@two.com""`

will work. instead i want to do something like

```
"Select * from contactTable where emails contains "email@two.com""
```

any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can you normalized your DB so that email and phone number are individual fields? MUCH simpler...

Comment: @n8wrl I think this is the right way, but many times we cannot do this due to many reasons (non-technical reasons). =)

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo: Understood. This just brings back bad memories from a past project where we stored XML as blobs. Impossible to search. Normalization was the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> "Select * from contactTable where emails contains "email@two.com""

I think you want:

"Select * from contactTable where thejsonfield -> emails

Example setup, after fixing up your totally  broken json:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts AS SELECT '{
    "firstName" : "First name",
    "lastName" : "Last name",
    "emails" : ["email@one.com", "email@two.com", "email@three.com"]
}'::json AS myjsonfield;
```

The following will work in PostgreSQL 9.4, but unfortunately does not in 9.3 due to the oversight of the missing `json_array_elements_text` function:

```
select * 
from contacts, 
lateral json_array_elements_text(myjsonfield -> 'emails') email
where email = 'email@two.com';
```

For 9.3, you have to use a clumsier method to scan the json array for matching values:

```
select * 
from contacts, 
lateral json_array_length(myjsonfield -> 'emails') numemails, 
lateral generate_series(0, numemails) n 
WHERE json_array_element_text(myjsonfield -> 'emails', n) = 'email@two.com';
```

You can't use the simple `IN` or `= ANY` constructs because (at this point) PostgreSQL doesn't understand that you might have a json array, so it'll fail with:

```
regress=> SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE 'email@two.com' = ANY (myjsonfield->'emails');
ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE 'email@two.com' = ANY (myjsonfi...
                                                     ^
```

as it expects a PostgreSQL array, not a json array, and there's no convenient builtin to turn a json array into a PostgreSQL array yet.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has support for parsing JSON. Here is documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html. I can't give you more detailed answer since you didn't provide exact data and schema, but it's easy to find the right function in documentation.